# Javascript block display to jQuery onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

So I got Javascript working brilliantly to display my DIV when I click on the button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function showDivToCart() {
   document.getElementById('header-cart').style.display = "block";
}
//]]>
</script>
```

The button looks like this:

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" id="product-addtocart-button" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this); showDivToCart();"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
```

Now I would like to change from this JS script to jQuery which would make it more easy to style and add additional options like fadeIn, fadeOut, etc. As I don't want to use any CSS.

I have got the following, but I have no idea where the mistake is. As this is for Magento, it could be a problem with noConflict function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$('#product-addtocart-button').click(function() {
        $("#header-cart").show('slow');
});
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As predicted I have found the solution with noconflict. Here is the code embeded inside my 'view.phtml'.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); 
$j(document).ready(function(){
    $j('#product-addtocart-button').click(function() {
        $j("#header-cart").fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: with in seconds you had found this ? or you have already an answer with you , and then ask a question and just give answer to it is it that way ?

Comment: While writing this I discovered the solution :)